# Compilation error fingerprint

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, qmake, fingerprint

```
cd bin/ && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jimmy/Downloads/fingerprint-gui-1.08/bin'
cd fingerprint-gui/ && make -f Makefile 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jimmy/Downloads/fingerprint-gui-1.08/bin/fingerprint-gui'
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o fingerprint-gui GlobalsImg.o DeviceHandler.o AboutImpl.o ExistDialogImpl.o Fingerprint.o FingerprintData.o UpekDevice.o GenericDevice.o FingerprintGUI.o MainWindowImpl.o SavedDialogImpl.o MessageDialogImpl.o PamTester.o xmlwriter.o UserSettings.o UsbDevice.o moc_DeviceHandler.o moc_AboutImpl.o moc_ExistDialogImpl.o moc_Fingerprint.o moc_FingerprintDevice.o moc_FingerprintData.o moc_MainWindowImpl.o moc_SavedDialogImpl.o moc_MessageDialogImpl.o moc_PamTester.o qrc_GUI-res.o qrc_About-res.o    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lusb-1.0 -lfprint -lpam -ldl -lqca -lpthread -lQtXml -lQtGui -lQtCore 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfprint
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:155: recipe for target 'fingerprint-gui' failed
make[2]: *** [fingerprint-gui] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jimmy/Downloads/fingerprint-gui-1.08/bin/fingerprint-gui'
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'sub-fingerprint-gui-make_default' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-fingerprint-gui-make_default] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jimmy/Downloads/fingerprint-gui-1.08/bin'
Makefile:39: recipe for target 'sub-bin-make_default' failed
make: *** [sub-bin-make_default] Error 2
```

This is output of make operation of pakage fingerprint.

During the process I also 3 times have some problem with enclude but I have resolve installing 3 pagkage using apt.

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: fingerprint
# Generated by qmake (2.01a) (Qt 4.8.7) on: Wed May 30 17:00:42 2018
# Project:  fingerprint.pro
# Template: subdirs
# Command: /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 PREFIX=/usr -o Makefile fingerprint.pro
#############################################################################

first: make_default
MAKEFILE      = Makefile
QMAKE         = /usr/bin/qmake-qt4
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
COPY          = cp -f
COPY_FILE     = $(COPY)
COPY_DIR      = $(COPY) -r
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
SUBTARGETS    =  \
        sub-bin

bin//$(MAKEFILE): 
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) bin/ || $(MKDIR) bin/ 
    cd bin/ && $(QMAKE) /home/jimmy/Downloads/fingerprint-gui-1.08/bin/bin.pro PREFIX=/usr -o $(MAKEFILE)
sub-bin-qmake_all:  FORCE
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) bin/ || $(MKDIR) bin/ 
    cd bin/ && $(QMAKE) /home/jimmy/Downloads/fingerprint-gui-1.08/bin/bin.pro PREFIX=/usr -o $(MAKEFILE)
sub-bin: bin//$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bin/ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE)
sub-bin-make_default: bin//$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bin/ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) 
sub-bin-make_first: bin//$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bin/ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) first
sub-bin-all: bin//$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bin/ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) all
sub-bin-clean: bin//$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bin/ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) clean
sub-bin-distclean: bin//$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bin/ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) distclean
sub-bin-install_subtargets: bin//$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bin/ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) install
sub-bin-uninstall_subtargets: bin//$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bin/ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) uninstall

Makefile: fingerprint.pro  /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/qmake.conf /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/linux.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/release.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/shared.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/moc.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/uic.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/include_source_dir.prf
    $(QMAKE) PREFIX=/usr -o Makefile fingerprint.pro
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/unix.conf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/linux.conf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/qconfig.pri:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/release.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/shared.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/moc.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/resources.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/uic.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/lex.prf:
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/include_source_dir.prf:
qmake: qmake_all FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) PREFIX=/usr -o Makefile fingerprint.pro

qmake_all: sub-bin-qmake_all FORCE

make_default: sub-bin-make_default FORCE
make_first: sub-bin-make_first FORCE
all: sub-bin-all FORCE
clean: sub-bin-clean FORCE
distclean: sub-bin-distclean FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile
install_subtargets: sub-bin-install_subtargets FORCE
uninstall_subtargets: sub-bin-uninstall_subtargets FORCE

upek-lib:
    install -d $(INSTALL_ROOT)/usr/lib; if uname -a | grep -q x86_64; then install -m 644 ./upek/lib64/libbsapi.so.4.0 ./upek/lib64/libbsapi.so.4.3 $(INSTALL_ROOT)/usr/lib; else install -m 644 ./upek/lib/libbsapi.so.4.0 ./upek/lib/libbsapi.so.4.3 $(INSTALL_ROOT)/usr/lib; fi; ldconfig

upek-rules:
    install -d $(INSTALL_ROOT)/etc/udev/rules.d; install -m 644 ./upek/91-fingerprint-gui-upek.rules $(INSTALL_ROOT)/etc/udev/rules.d

upek-cfg:
    install -d $(INSTALL_ROOT)/etc; install -m 644 ./upek/upek.cfg $(INSTALL_ROOT)/etc/upek.cfg

upek-dir:
    install -d $(INSTALL_ROOT)/var/upek_data; groupadd -f -r plugdev; chown root:plugdev $(INSTALL_ROOT)/var/upek_data; chmod 0775 $(INSTALL_ROOT)/var/upek_data

upek-udevadm:
    if command -v udevadm >/dev/null; then for ID in 2015 2016; do udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=usb --attr-match=idVendor=0483 --attr-match=idProduct=$ID; done; for ID in 2015 2016 2020 1000 1001 1002 1003 3000 3001 5002 5003; do udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=usb --attr-match=idVendor=147e --attr-match=idProduct=$ID; done; fi

install-upek: upek-lib upek-rules upek-cfg upek-dir upek-udevadm

uninstall-upek:
    rm -f $(INSTALL_ROOT)/usr/lib/libbsapi.so.4.0; rm -f $(INSTALL_ROOT)/usr/lib/libbsapi.so.4.3; rm -rf $(INSTALL_ROOT)/var/upek_data; rm -f $(INSTALL_ROOT)/etc/udev/rules.d/91-fingerprint-gui-upek.rules; ldconfig

user-data:
    find /var/lib/fingerprint-gui -exec chown root:root {} +; find /var/lib/fingerprint-gui -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +; find /var/lib/fingerprint-gui -type f -exec chmod 600 {} +; rm -f $(INSTALL_ROOT)/fingerprint-suid

sub-bin-check: bin/$(MAKEFILE)
    cd bin/ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) check
check: sub-bin-check

mocclean: compiler_moc_header_clean compiler_moc_source_clean

mocables: compiler_moc_header_make_all compiler_moc_source_make_all
install: install_subtargets  FORCE

uninstall:  uninstall_subtargets FORCE

FORCE:
```

I'm a biginner in make field and I realy don't know how I coudl interpet this output.

I'm using Debian.

Sorry I'm noob :D

Thanks for the help
Thanks for patience

Comment: The actual error is probably reported before the lines you quote.

Comment: Please include your Makefile so we can better address your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant info, don't post answers which aren't answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to install a few packages which the fingerprint package depends on. I just compiled `fingerprint-gui-1.08` in Debian 9 and to complete the build process I needed to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt install libfakekey-dev libfprint-dev libpam0g-dev libpolkit-qt-1-dev libqca2-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev qt4-dev-tools qt4-qmake
```

Remember to run `qmake-qt4` before running `make` as the `README` file says.